# bash script modify to take parameter from echo command

Tags: linux, bash, email, mandrill, getopt

I have [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blackdotsh/mandrillapp-cli/master/sendmail.sh) small bash script(sendmail.sh) to send emails using [mandril](http://mandrill.com/) which works super when used like this `./sendmail.sh "my@email.com" "Email Subject" "Email body"`. Thanks to [black @ LET](http://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/27009/sending-email-with-mandrillapp-api-and-bash) However I want this script to take its email body from echo command like the linux mail commands works . `echo "email body" | mail -s "email subject" email@any.com`

When I use the below script with this command `echo "email body" |./sendmail.sh "my@email.com" "Email Subject"` it prints the error specified in else block(since only 2 arguments are given but 3 needed) 
`/sendmail.sh requires 3 arguments - to address, subject, content
Example: ././sendmail.sh "to-address@mail-address.com" "test" "hello this is a test message"`

Surprised to see why `echo` commands output is not being taken as input for $3 argument in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#created by black @ LET
#MIT license, please give credit if you use this for your own projects
#depends on curl

key="" #your maildrill API key
from_email="" #who is sending the email
reply_to="$from_email" #reply email address
from_name="curl sender" #from name


if [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
    msg='{ "async": false, "key": "'$key'", "message": { "from_email": "'$from_email'", "from_name": "'$from_name'", "headers": { "Reply-To": "'$reply_to'" }, "return_path_domain": null, "subject": "'$2'", "text": "'$3'", "to": [ { "email": "'$1'", "type": "to" } ] } }'
    results=$(curl -A 'Mandrill-Curl/1.0' -d "$msg" 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json' -s 2>&1);
    echo "$results" | grep "sent" -q;
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "An error occured: $results";
        exit 2;
    fi
else
echo "$0 requires 3 arguments - to address, subject, content";
echo "Example: ./$0 \"to-address@mail-address.com\" \"test\" \"hello this is a test message\""
exit 1;
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is that surprising?  You are mixing arguments and standard input, which are fundamentally completely different.

However, it's not hard to accommodate this requirement.

```
case $# in
   3) text="$3" ;;
   2) text=$(cat) ;;
esac
: .... do stuff with "$text"
```

Your script has slightly sloppy indentation and quoting, so here is a somewhat refactored version.

```
key="" #your maildrill API key
from_email="" #who is sending the email
from_name="curl sender" #from name

case $# in
  3) text="$3";;
  2) text="$(cat)";;
  *) echo "$0: oops!  Need 2 or 3 arguments -- aborting" >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac

msg='{ "async": false, "key": "'"$key"'", "message": { "from_email": "'"$from_email"'", "from_name": "'"$from_name"'", "return_path_domain": null, "subject": "'"$2"'", "text": "'"$text"'", "to": [ { "email": "'"$1"'", "type": "to" } ] } }'
result=$(curl -A 'Mandrill-Curl/1.0' -d "$msg" 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json' -s 2>&1)
case $results in
  *"sent"*) exit 0;;
  *) echo "$0: error: $results" >&2; exit 2;;
esac
```

Notice in particular how any user-supplied string absolutely must be within double quotes.

(I took out `Reply-To:` because it's completely superfluous when it's equal to the `From:` header.)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution got worked. Yes I was mixing the two and got wrong there.